# Transpose Rows to Columns for Uknown mumber of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to transpose my rows to columns but I don't know the number of rows in my table. This example works for a static number of rows.  I've found several dynamic SQL examples on this site but I don't clearly understand how they work which is what I need.

```html
SELECT [9 payments], [Delay Tax return], [New Payment Schedule]
FROM
(SELECT RehabMetric, Reviews.ReviewID
FROM RehabMetricsCalls INNER JOIN
     RehabMetrics ON RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID = RehabMetrics.RehabMetricID INNER JOIN
     Reviews ON RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID = Reviews.ReviewID) AS pivTemp
PIVOT
(   COUNT(ReviewID)
    FOR RehabMetric IN ([9 payments], [Delay Tax return], [New Payment Schedule])
) AS pivTable

Table names:

*RehabMetrics*
RehabMetricID
RehabMetric

(Sample Data)
2, Nine Payments
7,Delay Tax Return
12, Continue Payments

*RehabMetricsCalls*
RehabMetricID
ReviewID

*Reviews*
ReviewID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you need to replace this part of your query

```
[9 payments], [Delay Tax return], [Delay Tax return]
```

by something dynamic.

Let's assume that there is a query returning your column names as for example

```
select name from some_table_with_your_column_names
```

where the result in your case is

```
name
---------------------
[9 payments]
[Delay Tax return]
[Delay Tax return]
```

So now let's try to answer your question

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max) = '';

select @columns = concat(@columns, iif(@columns <> '', '], ', ''), '[', name) 
from some_table_with_your_column_names
where name is not null
and name <> '';

if @columns <> '' begin
    select @columns = concat(@columns, ']');

    declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'select ' + @columns + ' from ( select RehabMetric, Reviews.ReviewID from RehabMetricsCalls inner join RehabMetrics ON RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID = RehabMetrics.RehabMetricID inner join Reviews ON RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID = Reviews.ReviewID) AS pivTemp pivot(  count(ReviewID) for RehabMetric in (' + @columns + ')) AS pivTable';

    execute sp_executesql @query;
end else begin
    -- do something else here if your column list is empty
end
```